# add any default field on select laravel eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

How I can added default field on query as

```
SELECT "default_value" as _my_special_virtual_field FROM ...
```

this method does not work as I expect

```
->addSelect(['"default_value" as _my_special_virtual_field'])
```

Comment: Show actual code, please.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use raw expressions:

```php
->addSelect(DB::raw('"default_value" as _my_special_virtual_field'))
->selectRaw('"default_value" as _my_special_virtual_field')
```

Comment: {
                "_my_special_virtual_field": "default_value",
            },
            {
                "id": 1,
                "user_id": 1,

Comment: What's the whole query?

Comment: Cards::where('user_id', '=', $userId)
            ->with('status')
            ->whereBetween('date', [$dateFrom, $dateTo])
            ->addSelect($this->db::raw('"default_value" as _my_special_virtual_field'))
            ->selectRaw('"default_value" as _my_special_virtual_field')
            ->get()
            ->toArray();

I expect
{id: 1, user_id:1, _my_special_virtual_field: default_value},{ ...}

Comment: You only need `addSelect()` or `selectRaw()`. Replace `->get() ->toArray()` with `->toSql()` and post the result.